# Process all/any link clicks on web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, virtual-machine

Some of my users need to use a virtual desktop to access some information on my site (I have a site outside the virtual desktop as well). In the virtual environment, there are links to the outside world which won't work. Is there any way (besides adding onClick functions one by one to each link, but I'll do this if necessary) to alert the user anytime they click a link that is not accessible inside the virtual environment? It just needs to popup an alert with an 'ok' button that ultimately does nothing/doesn't follow the link.

Note: The URL string is different in and out of the environment, so checking the href for certain strings would work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the URL in the href is going to determine if (certain) links will work, you could use the "starts with" (`^=`), "ends with" (`$=`), or "contains" (`*=`) selectors to select and disable the links that follow an external pattern.

For example, if all the external links that won't work are absolute and starts with the protocol (http or https), then you could do something like this when the page loads (in jQuery):

```
$('a[href=^="http"]').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("External links are not available");
});
```

That will take all the links starting with "http", preventing their default behavior and showing an error message to the user.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! However, I've tried to implement it but it does not work. The links still work.  Where should this code be placed? Also, is there documentation for the 'a[ref=^="http"]' piece so I can get a better idea of what's going on there?